# Bad practice to evaluate data in underscore.js micro template?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, underscore.js-templating

Are there any consequences of evaluating data in underscore micro templates?

for instance if we say we have this in our javascript file:

```
this.template({a: '10'});
```

And in our html template file

```
<%= a > 5 ? 'Val is larger than 5':'Val is smaller than 5' %>
```

Would it be better not to evaluate the data in the template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isnt a matter of seperation of concerns? You are injecting logic in a presentational "layer", potential bugs will be more difficult to track in my opinion.

Your example is simple, but imagine the scenario where you have something like

`<%= a > 10 ? (b > 20 ? " and b greater than 20" : " and b less than 20") : ( c > 20 ? " and c greater than 20" : " and c less than 20") %>`

Not readable at all.